# How to use python-firebase/Pyrebase with Kivy?

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, buildozer

What is the proper way to integrate Firebase into a kivy app?

I have tried to [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) and [python-fireabase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase). Was only able to implement Pyrebase. python-firebase seems to have some problems regarding the token generation, gonna tackle that later.

Simply importing Pyrebase as per docs works well with python. I was able to use as described. Building with Kivy, not so much.
Adding Pyrebase to requirements causes build to fail with error installing pycrypto, from Pyrebase requirements:

```
      checking whether the C compiler works... no
  configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-qHL810/pycrypto':
  configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
  See `config.log' for more details
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-qHL810/pycrypto/setup.py", line 456, in <module>
      core.setup(**kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/guga/HDD/Mega/Projetos/Olavo/SignInTests/.buildozer/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 199, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-qHL810/pycrypto/setup.py", line 251, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-qHL810/pycrypto/setup.py", line 278, in run
      raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
  RuntimeError: autoconf error

# Command failed: pip install --target=/home/guga/HDD/Mega/Projetos/Olavo/SignInTests/.buildozer/applibs pyrebase
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: It looks like there could be a problem with the python-for-android pycrypto build.

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you been able to build a project that requires pycrypto but not Pyrebase?  I have a spec file with pycrypto==2.6.1 working fine (on Android).

Comment: @Will I have moved on from this for the time being. Might give it another go sometime soon though. Thanks for the input.